# run inotifywait on background

Tags: bash, inotify, inotifywait

I have this code copied from linuxaria.com as example and work just fine on my case the problem is when I exit from terminal inotifywait stop. I want run on back ground even after exit the terminal. how I can do that?

```
#!/bin/sh

# CONFIGURATION
DIR="/tmp"
EVENTS="create"
FIFO="/tmp/inotify2.fifo"


on_event() {
  local date=$1
  local time=$2
  local file=$3

  sleep 5

  echo "$date $time Fichier créé: $file"
}

# MAIN
if [ ! -e "$FIFO" ]
then
  mkfifo "$FIFO"
fi

inotifywait -m -e "$EVENTS" --timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --format '%T %f' "$DIR" >       "$FIFO" &
INOTIFY_PID=$!


while read date time file
do
  on_event $date $time $file &
done < "$FIFO"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run the script with `screen` or `nohup` but I'm not sure how that would help since the script does not appear to log its output to any file.

```
nohup bash script.sh </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Or

```
screen -dm bash script.sh </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Disown could also apply:

```
bash script.sh </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown
```

You should just test which one would not allow the command to suspend or hang up when the terminal exits.

If you want to log the output to a file, you can try these versions:

```
nohup bash script.sh </dev/null >/path/to/logfile 2>&1 &
screen -dm bash script.sh </dev/null >/path/to/logfile 2>&1 &
bash script.sh </dev/null >/path/to/logfile 2>&1 & disown
```

Answer (score 7):

I made a 'service' out of it. So I could stop/start it like a normal service and also it would start after a reboot:

This was made on a Centos distro So I'm not if it works on others right away.

Create a file with execute right on in the service directory

/etc/init.d/*servicename*

```
#!/bin/bash

# chkconfig: 2345 90 60

case "$1" in
start)
   nohup SCRIPT.SH > /dev/null 2>&1 &
   echo $!>/var/run/SCRIPT.SH.pid
   ;;
stop)
   pkill -P `cat /var/run/SCRIPT.SH.pid`
   rm /var/run/SCRIPT.SH.pid
   ;;
restart)
   $0 stop
   $0 start
   ;;
status)
   if [ -e /var/run/SCRIPT.SH.pid ]; then
      echo SCRIPT.SH is running, pid=`cat /var/run/SCRIPT.SH.pid`
   else
      echo SCRIPT.SH is not running
      exit 1
   fi
   ;;
*)
   echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

Everything in caps you should change to what your script name.

The line `# chkconfig: 2345 90 60` makes it possible to start the service when the system is rebooted. this probably doens't work in ubuntu like distro's.

Answer (score 6):

The best way I found is to create a systemd service.

Create systemd file in `/lib/systemd/system/checkfile.service`:

```
sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/checkfile.service
```

And paste this there:

```
[Unit]
Description = Run inotifywait in backgoround

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
ExecStart=/bin/bash /path_to/script.sh
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and in `/path_to/script.sh`, you can have this:

```
inotifywait -m /path-to-dir -e create -e moved_to |
    while read dir action file; do
        echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$dir' via '$action'" >> /dir/event.txt
    done
```

Make sure that your file is executable by the user:

```
sudo chmod +x /path_to/script.sh
```

After creating two files, reload systemd manager configuration with:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now you can use start/stop/enable to your script:

```
sudo systemctl enable checkfile
sudo systemctl start checkfile
```

Make sure to replace file/directory/user/group values before executing.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. I wanted to monitor a folder for new files and send the filename with telegram

Answer (score 1):

replace -m with

> -d -o /dev/null

ie:

> inotifywait -d -o /dev/null -e "$EVENTS" --timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --format '%T %f' >"$DIR" > "$FIFO" & INOTIFY_PID=$!

You can check the inotifywait help manual at:

https://helpmanual.io/help/inotifywait/

Comment: Note that you cannot add any pipe action when using inotifywait -d. It will only print output to the file -> in this particular case it will actually do completely nothing as you nullify the output. Due to this, the -d usage for inotifywait has very limited usecases.

Answer (score 0):

Method that will work even if the file to be watched is not there yet, or gets deleted in between (just watch the whole directory instead of a single file, and then do the action on a particular file):

```
nohup inotifywait -m -e close_write /var/opt/some_directory/ |
while read -r directory events filename; do
  if [ "$filename" = "file_to_be_watched.log" ]; then
    # do your stuff here; I'm just printing the events to file
    echo "$events" >> /tmp/events.log
  fi
done &
```